# Unable to create Docker machine on Ubuntu (VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I am trying to install Docker and get it up and running on my machine. But let me tell you what OS I am using and how I am using it. I have a Windows 10 laptop. Then I installed Oracle VirtualBox on it. Then I installed Ubuntu on top of it. I am trying to install Docker and get it up and running on Ubuntu. I installed Docker.

```
sudo snap install docker

sudo apt  install docker-compose
```

Then I tried to boost up the Docker Compose of my project running the following command.

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

Then I got the following error.

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
```

Then I tried to create the Docker machine because there is no default machine. I run the following command.

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
```

Then I got the following error.

```
Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"
```

Then I tried installing the VirtualBox running the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox

sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ext-pack
```

It was successfully installed. I tried running the following command again.

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
```

I am still getting the same error. What is missing in my configuration and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should not need `docker-machine` or VirtualBox in this setup (you are already running inside a VM).  I've seen other SO issues suggesting that using `snap` to install Docker doesn't work well; you should figure out why the daemon isn't starting, and possibly reinstall Docker using APT.

Comment: Yes, please follow the official installation guide https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: VBoxManage.exe is in the "c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\" in the Host machine. Either you should running it from there or set PATH to access that folder.